# Firebase Crashlytics debug mode not send report in ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-crash-reporting

in swift, how to send crash report only release mode?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

#if DEBUG
    Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
#endif

    return true
}
```

is it right?
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate.

```
    #if DEBUG
    Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
    Crashlytics.crashlytics().checkForUnsentReports { isUnsendExists in
        if isUnsendExists {
            Crashlytics.crashlytics().deleteUnsentReports()
        }
    }
    #else
    Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
    #endif
```